# Direct3D12 Device creation fails with DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: direct3d

i'm trying to start d3d12 developement with the windows 10 preview Build 10074 and the Visual Studio 2015 RC Pro

But i'm getting DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED "The specified device or feature level is not supported on this system" when I try to create the ID3D12Device

```
HRESULT hr = D3D12CreateDevice(0, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, __uuidof(ID3D12Devie), (void**)&device);
```

I'm working on a Laptop with 2 Gpus:

- Intel Hd Graphics 4600, WDDM 1.3(dxdiag)
- Nvidia 765M GTX, WDDM 2.0(dxdiag)

Well the intel gpu has the wrong driver model, but the nvidia gpu should match the d3d12 requirements at least for feature level 11.

I have tried to start visual studio with with Rightclick->Graphicprocessor->NVIDIA and to start the exe directly but it makes no difference.

Did I miss something?

Comment: The problem may be that you are using 'null' for the pAdapter which is trying to use the Intel driver instead. You can try explicitly enumerating the device and using the NVIDIA one rather than passing null.

Comment: Its a good hint to make sure what adapter is used but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it works, I needed the newest NVIDIA Driver (352.84) released few days ago.

Well Windows 10 has updated my intel driver as well so it works with both GPUs now.

Both use WDDM 2.0 now.

Comment: Makes sense it would be an outdated driver. You should sign up for [DirectX 12 Early Access](http://1drv.ms/1dgelm6) for best support.